# mongodb compact does nothing - no entry in mongodb.log and nothing in db.currentOp()

Tags: mongodb, disk-space, database-size, mongo-repair

We have space problems. The actual data size is only 5 GB, but disk size is 15 GB because of deleted documents. MongoDB (3.0.6) runs in docker container where we can't extend volume.

```
# tail -f mongod.log
2016-04-26T14:43:59.631+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] allocating new datafile /data/work/mongodb/data/opWNFbyNlGQ6xShT.11, filling with zeroes...
2016-04-26T14:43:59.632+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] FileAllocator: posix_fallocate failed: errno:28 No space left on device falling back
2016-04-26T14:43:59.632+0000 I STORAGE  [FileAllocator] error: failed to allocate new file: /data/work/mongodb/data/opWNFbyNlGQ6xShT.11 size: 2146435072 failure creating new datafile; lseek failed for fd 40 with errno: errno:2 No s^C
```

disk

```
/dev/vdh                            16G   15G  553M  97% /data/a6a186a3-dc98-4f47-83f3-96e953c18b69
```

repairDatabase doesn't work because no scratch space

```
> db.runCommand( { repairDatabase: 1 } );
{
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "Cannot repair database opWNFbyNlGQ6xShT having size: 14975762432 (bytes) because free disk space is: 578928640 (bytes)",
        "code" : 14031
}
```

So I tried

```
> db.runCommand ( { compact: 'accounts', paddingFactor: 1.1 } )
{ "ok" : 1 }
```

I don't see nothing in progress

```
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
> db.currentOp()
{ "inprog" : [ ] }
```

There is no entry in `mongodb.log` about the compact operation

> You may view the intermediate progress either by viewing the mongod
>   log file or by running the db.currentOp() in another shell instance.

[compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/command/compact/)

Why compact fails?

is our only solution to do dump/drop/restore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the MMAP storage engine there are several factors to be aware of:

- The `compact` command only defragments data files & indexes in MMAP; it does not release unused space to the operating system. Running `compact` can still be useful to [reduce fragmentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/storage/#empty-records) and encourage free space reuse, but will not help if your disk space is critically low.
- The `compact` command in MMAP requires [additional disk space (up to 2GB)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/#mmapv1) during the compact operation.
- As at MongoDB 3.2, `compact` is a blocking command (database-level lock for the collection being compacted).

The approach to reclaiming preallocated space in MMAPv1 is rebuilding the database either through a [resync (recommended for replica sets)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/) or a [repair (the only option for standalone deployments)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/).

> repairDatabase doesn't work because no scratch space

You can use the command line option [`--repairpath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#cmdoption--repairpath) or the config file option [`storage.repairPath`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.repairPath) to provide extra storage (i.e. a second volume) for working space during the repair process:

```
mongod --repair --repairpath /path/to/extraspace --dbpath ...
```

After the repair process completes, the rebuilt data files will reside in the `dbpath` and the `repairpath` should be empty.

#### WiredTiger Storage Engine

If you have the option of upgrading to the WiredTiger storage engine in future, it has many improvements over MMAP:

- Data files and indexes are [compressed by default](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression) (with configurable compression options that can be set globally or per collection).
- The `compact` command can release storage to the O/S (MongoDB 3.2.3+).
- Minimal additional space should be required in order to run the `compact` command.